# Cookies are not shared on the same computer

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I found on internet that the cookie is attached to a domain.
If I use windows cmd console I can see my domain name is MSI which translates to my local IP address `192.168.0.19`.
Why is it then when I use different logins to my google accounts using chrome and I connect using swagger to my locally running c# application, I have different cookie for each login - they are not shared.
I have checked that tabs are sharing cookies (that is true) but not logins?
Am I missing something?